# How to find last row which have data

Tags: vba

I am looking for VBA Code to get the row number of Last row which have data in any column i.e **I want to search in whole worksheet**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Thx but I don't know the column index so I Cant use that. 
:(

Comment: Please check the code in that link which uses `.Find`. You do not need Column index for that...

Comment: You should try googling it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.count
```

upd: link in question's comments says you should not use UsedRange